# How to make an HTML element ignore the position of another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<section>` tag used as a container for multiple other elements. As a sibling of the `<section>` tag, I have an `<h1>` used as a timer of sorts. The thing is, the `<section>` tag is positioned exactly how I want it to *without* the `<h1>`, and when the `<h1>` exists, it moves the `<section>` tag over. How can I use the `<h1>` tag without moving the `<section>` tag over? Thanks!
(Required CSS below)

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* The <h1> mentioned above*/
.timer {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: roboto;
    color: #F6E71D;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 25px;
}

/*The container mentioned above*/
#card-container {
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="timer">Time left: </h1>
    <section id="card-container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back">
                <img class="logo" src="assets/logo.svg" alt="logo.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front">
                <h1 class="symbol">X</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back">
                <img class="logo" src="assets/logo.svg" alt="logo.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front">
                <h1 class="symbol">X</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code, too?

Comment: The HTML was added in, thanks.

Comment: I have updated your question with a runnable, code snippet.  Without the resolving images, it might not look quite perfect (feel free to edit, to make it even more clear, what the problem is).  Btw, have you tried things like style="margin-right:-20px;", or some such?  Or is that not exactly what you're looking to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not quite what I'm looking for. If you take out the `h1` tag, the position of the `section` is perfect. However, with the `h1` tag, it moves over to the right. My question asks how can I keep the `h1` tag, but not have the whole `section` move over towards the right.

Comment: You want the `section` tag to move down below the `h1`?

Comment: Where do you want your h1 to be positioned ?

Comment: @Joulss in the top left corner.

Comment: @vmank, no the `section` tag should stay exactly where it is as though the `h1` tag was not there.

Comment: You can use `position: fixed; top:0; left:0;` on the `h1`. Not sure if that's what you want though.

Comment: Like others say, we're not sure where you want the h1 tag.  I added the code snippet so you could edit it or say specifically how it's not working.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve here. We need you to give us more context.

Comment: @Ted, that's exactly the solution! Thank you so much! To everyone else, the `h1` was supposed to be in the top left corner of the screen, and the `section` tag should have its position unchanged.

Comment: @vmank, I understand and apologize for the confusion I caused. Ted's answer did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have the timer in the top left and not affect other elements, give it the css property `position: absolute;` and do the rest of your styling to put things where you want them. This way it doesn't affect the positioning of other elements. I would highly recommend the use of flexbox or css grid if you haven't looked into them yet. It makes layout styling easier.

Comment: @lionrocker221 It's good to note the position and dimensions of an element with position:absolute are relative to its containing block, the position and dimensions of an element with position:fixed are always relative to the viewport. So either will work, but one may be better for your application. That's your call.